# Java, Class' s property is not updated when it is changed with method

Tags: java, c#, oop, debugging, neural-network

App Link: [Replit](https://replit.com/@mutludev/EveryVengefulPiracy)

I have a Neuron_ class

```
public class Neuron_ {
  private double[] weights;
  double learningRate;

  public Neuron_ (int inputNeurons, double learningRate) {
    this.weights = new double[inputNeurons];
    this.learningRate = learningRate;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputNeurons; i++) {
      this.weights[i] = Math.random();
    }
  }

  public double calculate(double[] inputs) {
    double output = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      output += inputs[i] * this.weights[i];
    }
    return output;
  }

  public void decreaseWeight(double[] inputs) {    
    for (int i = 0; i < this.weights.length; i++) {
      this.weights[i] -= learningRate * inputs[i] ;
    }
  }

  public void increaseWeight(double[] inputs) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.weights.length; i++) {
      this.weights[i] += learningRate * inputs[i] ;
    }
  }
}
```

and I call increaseWeight and decreaseWeight methods from NeuralNetwork class

```
if(biggestIndex != correctIndex) {
      System.out.println("Wrong output, changing weights");
      for (int i = 0; i < this.neurons.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < outputNeurons.length; j++) {
          System.out.println("Changing weights for neuron " + i + " for output " + outputNeurons[j]);
          if (j == correctIndex) {
            this.neurons[i].increaseWeight(inputs);
          } else if (j == biggestIndex) {
            this.neurons[i].decreaseWeight(inputs);
          }
        }
    }
    }
```

neurons array is created like this

```
  public NeuralNetwork_ (int inputNeurons, String[] outputNeurons, double learningRate) {
    this.outputNeurons = outputNeurons;
    this.neurons = new Neuron_[outputNeurons.length];
    for(int i = 0; i<outputNeurons.length; i++) {
      this.neurons[i] = new Neuron_(inputNeurons, learningRate);
    }
  }
```

When I call decreaseWeight and increaseWeight methods from another class, Logs show like they were changed but when I log weights at the beginning and at the end of the training, they were same every time.

weights array is not updating.

Comment: 1. Why is this tagged java and c#? Are you unsure what language you are coding in? 2. Please show how you print out those values. The error might be there and if you don't show all code for a complete example that demonstrates the problem, figuring out where you made a mistake is kind of hard. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: it is written in java, and this is the full code.  https://replit.com/@mutludev/EveryVengefulPiracy weights are printed before and after changing them @oh-god-spiders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

weights change, but finally the result is the same for maths ops.
Try modify you method with more log:

```
  public void decreaseWeight(double[] inputs) {
    double[] newWeights = new double[inputs.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.weights.length; i++) {
      newWeights[i] = this.weights[i] - learningRate;
    }
    this.weights = newWeights;
  System.out.println("intermedial weights: " + Arrays.toString(this.weights));

  }

  public void increaseWeight(double[] inputs) {
    double[] newWeights = new double[inputs.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.weights.length; i++) {
      newWeights[i] = this.weights[i] + learningRate;
    }
    this.weights = newWeights;
    System.out.println("intermedial weights: " + Arrays.toString(this.weights));
}
```

and study the result.

[image: debug]

For each neurons iterator you are increasing and then decreasing weights whith the same value, so finally neuron weights are the same

Comment: I log them after every change but after one iteration they log back the same thing for ex.

Old value: 0.25
New value: 0.75

Next Iteration
Old value: 0.25
New value: 0.50

Code is linked top of the question.
@rubén-aguado

Comment: @SultanDelen, simplify your code and post it